# Patch for new 64bit kernel vulnerability?

Tags: server, upgrade, kernel, security

I read about the 64 bit kernel vulnerability in the linux kernel today (9/20) [Link to article](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=9574)
  I have an ubuntu server 10.04 and 8.04 in my organization.  My question is could I just use the apt-get utility or the aptitude safe-upgrade to patch these kernels - but is the 64 bit kernel patch included in those updates I would download?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have gotten them through the updates... according to this they went out the 17th:

http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-988-1

Answer (score 3):

When wondering about these things, you can always check the changelog files for your installed kernels. For example, first make sure you're up to date:

$ `sudo apt-get update`

$ `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Then you can check what happened in the latest kernel update:

$ `cd $(ls -dtr /usr/share/doc/linux-image-* | tail -n1)`

$ `zcat changelog.Debian.gz | head -n10`

```
linux (2.6.32-24.43) lucid-security; urgency=low

  [ Upstream Kernel Changes ]

  * x86-64, compat: Test %rax for the syscall number, not %eax
    - CVE-2010-3301
      * x86-64, compat: Retruncate rax after ia32 syscall entry tracing
    - CVE-2010-3301
  * compat: Make compat_alloc_user_space() incorporate the access_ok()
    - CVE-2010-3081
```

Then you can compare what kernel you have running against the latest changelog, and reboot if you haven't already:

$ `cat /proc/version_signature`

```
 Ubuntu 2.6.32-24.43-server 2.6.32.15+drm33.5
```

Comment: Wow this is a good answer too.  Thanks for the info.